Are there any harms of chanting Saraswati Beeja mantras?
The Saraswati Beeja mantras have aim , hreem and Kling as its Beeja mantra. As Saraswati is a saumya Devi and not a ugra Devi like maa Kali and Tara can one chant the Beeja mantras of maa Saraswati ?  Will there be any harm by doing the Beeja mantras? Also I donot know whether any sampradaya gives any initiation to sarswati mantras, are we eligible to chant the Saraswati mantra and benifit from it? Thank you

There are three types (categories) of Mantras viz. Vedic (वैदिक), Tantric (तांत्रिक), and Shaabar (शाबर).

Vedic Mantras - are part of 4 Vedas (Samhitas) and hence composed as Sanskrit text. The example is : Gayatri Mantra

Tantric Mantras - originate from various Tantric text. And they were also composed in Sanskrit. The example is : Navaaran Mantra (नवार्ण मंत्र) mentioned in Durga Sapt-Shati (दुर्गा सप्तशती).

Shaabar Mantras - these mantras are of rustic origin - and hence are available in different local languages of India / Indian Sub-continent.


Before, one decides to start chanting any Vedic or Tantric mantra, its absolutely mandatory for any person to be initiated by a competent / living guru. Therefore, it is not advisable to read mantra from any books or online sources and start practicing it.
Yes, people claim that they know this or that shaabar mantra from some or the other sources - and personally I have no opinion on that.
Now, coming to the specifically mentioned Beej Mantra in this question...
The statement "The Saraswati Beeja mantras have aim , hreem and Kling as its Beeja mantra." - is itself an incorrect statement.
The Beej Mantra of Devi (Goddess) Sarasvati is "Aim" i.e. ऐं  - This is a Tantric Beeja Mantra.
Similarly, "Hreem" i.e. ह्रीं - is the Beeja Mantra of Devi Mahalakshmi. It is also called Maya Beeja.
Finally, "Kleem" i.e क्लीं - is the Beeja Mantra of Devi Mahakali.
Ma Durga (Goddess Durga) - represents the amalgamation of aforesaid three Devis viz. Mahakali, Mahalakshmi and Mahasarasvati and hence its only Her mantra which has all these 3 Beejas i.e. ऐं, ह्रीं and क्लीं.
In Hinduism / Sanatana Dharma traditions - one can start her / his saadhana -with any God / Goddess - and still may reach to the same spiritual destination. So its your guru and family traditions decides by which Mantra, one shall be initiated by her / his guru.
And without proper initiation (Diksha / दीक्षा) - one should never start chanting these Vedic as well as Tantric Mantras.
